# Using the CSS style format in GeoServer, how can you sort-by on a value returned from a function, i.e. the x value of a polygon’s centroid

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-css-module

### Work in progress

I’m currently working on a CSS style in GeoServer where the US states are extruded based on population (PERSONS). In order to get a 2.5D effect a combination of the isometric and offset functions needs to work in conjunction and drawn in a specific order.

[image: US States - Population]

### Dificulty

From the picture above one can see that NY (New York) are drawn on top of PA (Pennsylvania). I therefore would like to specify the drawing order based on the x value of the polygon’s centroid.   I’m also all ears if there is a better solution because I don’t believe sorting by the x value will eliminate all problem areas.

### Tried and Failed

To get the x value of the polygon’s centroid, one can use this function:
`[getX(centroid(the_geom))]`.

When applying this to the sort-by function I get the following error:

```
sort-by: [getX(centroid(the_geom))];
```

*Cannot turn this value into a literal: Expression [expression=getX([centroid([the_geom])])]*

### Full code

```
@mode "Flat";

* {  
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-opacity: 1;
  stroke-width:3;
  z-index:0;
}

* {
  fill: #7B7B7B;
  fill-geometry: [isometric(the_geom, PERSONS/8000000)];

  stroke: #636363;
  stroke-geometry: [isometric(the_geom, PERSONS/8000000)];
  stroke-opacity:0.7;
  sort-by: PERSONS;  
  z-index:0;
}

* {

  fill-geometry: [offset(the_geom, 0, PERSONS/8000000)];
  stroke-geometry: [offset(the_geom, 0, PERSONS/8000000)];
  fill: #CACCCD;
  stroke: #000000;
  stroke-opacity: 0.7;
  sort-by: PERSONS;
  z-index:0;
}

*{
  label-geometry: [(centroid(offset(the_geom, 0, PERSONS/8000000)))];
  label-anchor: 0.5 0.5;
  label: [STATE_ABBR];

  font-family: "Arial";
  font-fill:black;
  font-size:12;
  halo-color: white;
  halo-radius: 1.5;
}
```

So in this example I would like to replace the `sort-by: Persons` with `sort-by: x` value of polygon centroid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that, not in CSS, nor in any other language: such functionality is missing at the rendering engine level. Not trivially implemented either, but if you are interested, hop on the geotools-devel mailing list and ask for directions, happy to give you some.

If you want to play with configuration only, and have a spatial database in the backend, maybe try to setup a SQL view that does the sorting you want directly in the database.